# Initializing a resource in ServletContextListener and accessing one in Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a web-application, which I deploy into tomcat.

My need is to programmatically initialize some resource on application startup, which then should be available inside `Servlet` (even worse - inside `Service` implementation - I use CFX and it is a SOAP webservice).
I used several times `ServletContextListener` to define some global application tasks, like setting up scheduler, but this time I need to access my resourse from the Servlet, and have no clue how.

How can I initialize my resource once on app startup and access it from servlet, this way or another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ContextListener set the resource as attribute in the `ServletContext` and access it within the servlet via `ServletContext.getAttribute`.